# How to reproduce exception: System.OverflowException: "Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte."

Tags: c#, .net

I'm attempting to reproduce the following exception:

> System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.

from the following code:

```cs
object data;
// ... "data" is populated by client data ...
data = new string(Array.ConvertAll((byte[])data, Convert.ToChar));
```

The error is resulting from client data, but I'm simply trying to reproduce the same exception.  How can I populate `data` to reproduce the same exception?

Stacktrace is:

```plaintext
System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.
   at System.Convert.ToByte(Char value)
   at System.Array.ConvertAll[TInput,TOutput](TInput[] array, Converter`2 converter)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Convert.ToByte(500);` will throw that.

Comment: @David Browne: yes, but we convert `(byte[])data`, so either `(byte[])` *cast fails* or we have a *valid* byte array `byte[]`, and no chances to throw the exception on `byte` to `char` conversion

Comment: Is there possibility that the exception has been thrown somewhere in the `// ... "data" is populated by client data ...`?

Comment: not from the stacktrace.  Could it be throwing on `(byte[])data`?

Comment: What type is `data`?

Comment: It's binary data.  Sorry - that's all I know.  Possibly barcode data.

Comment: Look at remarks at this documentation about ToByte. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobyte?view=net-6.0#System_Convert_ToByte_System_Char_

You pass Convert.ToChar to Array.ConvertAll, so each 16 bits of data passed to .ToByte as a Char, and yes it is possible to get a Char that have value greater than 255.

Comment: That makes sense - thank you all.  The source for `Array.ConvertAll` shows that it is simply doing a `Convert.ToByte()` like @DavidBrowne-Microsoft suggested as well.  I'll keep trying to create some data to reproduce.
https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/array.cs